# Перепутаны заголовок и описание?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, локализация, причины-закрытия

Мне кажется, у этих двух причин закрытия вопросов перепутаны заголовок и описание (хоть и по-английски):

[image]

More details and clarify и означает конкретизировать, а непонятна суть вопроса как раз когда несколько вопросов или вообще ни одного.

Answer (score 2):

Тут всё нормально. В частности, см. [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9877/176217).

- Необходимо конкретизировать - это [Needs more focus](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13582).
  Много всего написано и нужно оставить что-то одно, выкинув лишнее.

---

- Непонятная суть вопроса - это [Needs details or clarity](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13560).
  Что-то написано, но для понимания вопроса не хватает информации. Нужно добавить пояснений.