# Названия причин закрытия вопросов

Tags: предложение, локализация, тревоги, причины-закрытия

До обновления в движке, из-за которого некоторое время причины писались по-английски, были такие причины:

> - Вопрос слишком общий
> - Необходимо переформулировать так чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ
> - Не понятна суть вопроса

Мне они нравятся больше, чем теперешние. Может их стоит поменять назад?

**UPD**

Согласен "мне нравятся больше" — это не аргумент. Но старые причины привычней. И соответственно будут правильнее использоваться

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предыдущие причины:

- Too broad -> Слишком общий
- Unclear what are you asking -> Непонятна суть вопроса
- Opinion based -> Необходимо переформулировать так чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ

Текущие причины:

- Needs more focus -> Необходимо конкретизировать
- Needs details or clarity -> Непонятна суть вопроса
- Opinion based -> Невозможно дать объективный ответ

На первый взгляд, формулировки не сильно отличаются от старых. Смысл изменений в том, чтобы подчеркнуть, какие действия требуются от автора вопроса для переоткрытия. Если вы хотите их изменить, пожалуйста, дайте более весомые доводы, чем "мне нравятся больше".

Comment: Согласен "мне нравятся больше" — это не аргумент. Но старые причины привычней. И соответственно будут правильнее использоваться...