# Объединить две причины закрытия "Непонятна суть вопроса" и "Необходимо конкретизировать"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, причины-закрытия

По сути они несут одну и ту же смысловую нагрузку: недостаточно данных для ответа на вопрос. Поэтому, на мой взгляд, их можно было бы объединить, скажем, в "Уточните вопрос" или что-то такое, что тем самым ускорило бы работу проверяющих при выборе причины для закрытия вопроса. Сейчас же это читается как единое целое:

```
Непонятна суть вопроса —> Необходимо конкретизировать (уточнить)
```

Comment: Я за. Я вообще за старые варианты ,но их вряд ли вернуть. А вообще это действительно одно и тоже.

Comment: Вообще эти причины разные, для разных типов вопросов

Comment: @Grundy действия, которое требуется от пользователя при указании оных — одно. Мы же закрываем их не ради закрытия, как такового.

Comment: @Grundy да какие они разные, одно и то же. Даже в описании одной причины повторяется другая причина  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9873/282277

Comment: @Grundy нет....

Comment: @grundy конкретизируйте пожалуйста

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что причины разные. *"Непонятна суть вопроса"* - автор показал код или рассказал, что он пытается сделать, но забыл сказать, в чем именно вопрос. *"Необходимо конкретизировать"* - автор задал несколько вопросов в одном вопросе. Либо вопрос слишком широкий, и нормальный ответ на него тянет на целую статью/книгу.

Comment: "Необходимо конкретизировать" - это аналог старой причины "Слишком общий": https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9877/240512 Смысл не изменился, изменили только формулировку. Если различие между новыми причинами непонятно, можно поменять переводы. Сейчас там получилось кто в лес, кто по дрова: у одних дословный перевод новой формулировки, у других старая, у третьих - что-то среднее.